# Qual é o nome dumas saliências transversais nas lombadas de alguns livros de capa de couro?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

Muitos livros antigos encadernados a couro têm umas coisas salientes atravessadas nas lombadas, que eu assinalei na figura abaixo. Aquilo é os fios que unem as folhas que passam por baixo daquilo. Mas qual é o nome daquilo?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um termo que encontrei foi **nervura**:

- Segundo a [Infopedia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/nervuras): *saliência transversal na lombada dos livros encadernados*
- [Neste artigo](https://siaiap32.univali.br/seer/index.php/rc/article/view/2256/1721) é mencionando, na página 4 do PDF, vários significados de "nervura", entre eles: *Na tipografia, "nervura" se refere à saliência transversal das lombadas dos livros encadernados.*

No livro intitulado "Livro" (Michel Melot), há também [uma referência](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=pje_wVDGKucC&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=saliencias%20dos%20livros&source=bl&ots=nCKmI8jALf&sig=70AMK_ZJjA73kgU9ZFNfdquGmI8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinzYHj5PDVAhWLg5AKHQIBC1MQ6AEISjAF#v=onepage&q=sali&f=false) ao termo **nervo**:

> No passado, as encadernações dos livros eram mantidas por um sistema complicado de fios cosidos sobre os cadernos, o que os deixava salientes no dorso. Estas saliências dos **nervos** marcavam linhas horizontais paralelas, deixando-as bem visíveis sob a cobertura do couro. As técnicas de encadernação há muito tornaram desnecessárias estas saliências, as quais, entretanto, continuam marcadas por aquilo que os encadernadores chamam de "falsos **nervos**".

Comment: Muito bem. Vem noutros dicionários também. Como é que descobriste? Intuição mais confirmação?

Comment: @Jacinto Na verdade, fui no google e procurei *"saliências transversais nos livros"*, *"saliências nas lombadas dos livros"* e outras variações (incluindo ou não outros termos como "tipografia", "encadernado" e fazendo várias combinações). Eu também não fazia ideia que tinha um nome só para aquilo. E acabei encontrando outra referência relacionada, atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Eu já tinha procurado, mas não tinha achado nada. O [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/nervura) também fala em nervos.

Comment: Agora fiquei curioso em ver um vídeo mostrando o cosimento das nervuras!